# в определённый момент выдаёт undefined не могу понять почему

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--  функция рандома числа относительно варианта -->

var a = 14;

function prov_var(Nomer_var) {
    if (Nomer_var % 2 == 0) {
        return true;
    } <!--чётное-->
    else {
        return false;
    } <!--не чётное--> 

}
<!--  функция рандома числа относительно варианта КОНЕЦ-->

<!-- формирование числа относитьльно проверки на четность -->
function meshalka(n) {
    var hui = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
    if (n == true) {
        while (hui % 2 != 0 && hui != 4 && hui != 8) {
            hui = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);

        }
        return hui;
    } else {
        while (hui % 2 == 0) {
            hui = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);

        }
        return hui;
    }
}
<!-- формирование числа относитьльно проверки на четность КОНЕЦ-->


<!-- проверка что число нехорошее -->
function prov_hu(n) {
    switch (n) {
        case 4:
            return false;
            break;
        case 8:
            return false;
            break;
        default:
            return true;
    }

}

function final_prov() {
    var prov = meshalka(prov_var(a));
    if (prov_hu(prov) == true) {
        return prov;
    } else {
        final_prov();
    }

}

<!-- проверка что число нехорошее КОНЕЦ-->
document.write(final_prov());

</script>
```

Comment: Во-первых я рекомендовал бы быть аккуратнее с названием переменных по типу hui. Это может заставить работать некоторые интерпретаторы (например тот что в голове преподавателя) работать неправильно

Comment: Во-вторых, обратите внимание, вы пишете в документ результат выполнения функции final_prov, а она может в нижней ветке ничего не вернуть. Ничего - это и есть undefined. Да, понятно что вы задумали некоторую рекурсию, и проверка пойдет себе дальше рекурсивно выполняться, но в момент когда вы именно записываете, записывать нечего.

Comment: вы хоть опишите что ваш код вообще делает, мы тут разбираться должны сами что ли? тем более кода в 3 раза больше чем надо

Comment: в последней функции надо `return final_prov()` сделать, а не просто вызвать `final_prov()`